# Jetpack Compose semicircle using Canvas

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-canvas

I am trying to create a semicircle speed progress bar in Jetpack Compose. Unless the view is square the semicircle will not look as expected, if I use 1:2 width: height it will be flattened. I want a Composable representing half of the circle where I don't have unusable bottom half of the view.

```
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.size(300.dp)) {
            drawArc(
                color = Color.LightGray,
                -180f,
                180f,
                useCenter = false,
                style = Stroke(8.dp.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
            )
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.Center),
            text = "20 Mbps",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 20.sp
        )
    }
```

[image]

The expected outcome would be a reusable semicircle composable with a height of the actual semicircle so I can easily position other content against it. The expected view size is marked by a dotted green line.

[image]

Comment: It's not flattened. A rectangle, square when dimension are equal, is used as reference to draw arc. What you ask is, if you want radius of circle to be equal to half of the width of the canvas in second image is not possible. You can draw a circle or half circle with radius that s not bigger than half of the height of the second canvas. You can also draw a circle less than half on screen using `topLeft` with a minus value and `size` parameters.

Comment: Hi @Thracian. It becomes completely flat if I try to move it down using Y Offset in topLeft  
topLeft = Offset(0f, (diameter / 2).toPx()), or topLeft = Offset(0f, (diameter / 2).toPx()).
Path contains a method addArc which takes a rectangle of your chosen size and it allows me to draw a filled half circle but what I really need is a line arc with round stroke caps.

Comment: Yes. That's the rectangle reference i mentioned. You draw your arc based on offset, size which translates to a rectangle with swipe and start angles, by default it's your DrawScope or Canvas size with `this.size.offsetSize(topLeft)`. Do you have an image of what you wish to achieve. I couldn't picture it

Comment: I have updated the question to show the expected outcome which is a semicircle progress track (grey), progress track (light green). The height of the Composable being 1/2 width and text showing speed in the middle of the composable which would be super-easy if the height was representing what you see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i mentioned in comments arc uses rectangle if you want a semi arc that covers whole hight just double the height you draw arc with

```
@Composable
private fun ArcComposable(modifier: Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {
        Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .size(300.dp)
            .clipToBounds()) {
            drawArc(
                color = Color.LightGray,
                -180f,
                180f,
                useCenter = false,
                size = Size(size.width, size.height * 2),
                style = Stroke(8.dp.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
            )
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.Center),
            text = "20 Mbps",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 20.sp
        )
    }
}
```

I added Modifier.clipToBounds() because of strokeCap round which is added to length of the line by default. You can just reduce size and height few px to match inside the canvas. Canvas by default even if you don't set a modifier with size it draws anything out of its bounds unless you use `Modifier.clipToBounds()`

[image]

```
private fun ArcComposable(modifier: Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .background(Color.Red)
    ) {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(300.dp)
//            .clipToBounds()
        ) {
            drawArc(
                color = Color.LightGray,
                -180f,
                180f,
                useCenter = false,
                topLeft = Offset(4.dp.toPx(), 6.dp.toPx()),
                size = Size(size.width - 8.dp.toPx(), size.height * 2 - 20.dp.toPx()),
                style = Stroke(8.dp.toPx(), cap = StrokeCap.Round)
            )
        }
        Text(
            modifier = Modifier.align(alignment = Alignment.Center),
            text = "20 Mbps",
            color = Color.White,
            fontSize = 20.sp
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Here, i also add another one with topLeft and size reduction to cover rounded.  And i have a tutorial that covers drawing arcs and many things related to canvas. You can check it here https://github.com/SmartToolFactory/Jetpack-Compose-Tutorials

Comment: Now it's perfect, thanks. I will check out your tutorials, thanks for all the effort :)